# Simple ruby script to process queue using multithreading throws Deadlock error?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Before I summarize my question I want to say that I've already read all other questions regarding this error message and they all seem to apply to specific gems which I'm not working with. I'm kind of an intermediate Ruby scripter and I'm brand new to Threads so I'm having trouble understanding what this error even means let alone finding out how to fix it.

My best guess is that the threads are being run faster than the producer can put them in the queue? But I tried to solve for that by adding a sleep interval on each set of 5 threads and it still runs into the error by the end of running.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:
I want to load a list of rows from a csv file into a queue, then process those rows from that queue using multithreading.

Here is my code which is only printing values right now because I want to get the multithreading working properly before I attempt to actually do anything with the data.

```rb
require 'csv'
require 'thread'

count = 0
num_threads = 5
Thread.abort_on_exception = true

queue = ::Queue.new
producer = ::Thread.new do
    user_list = CSV.table(ARGV.first).map { |row| row.to_hash }
    user_list.each do |row|
        queue << row
    end
end

threads = 1.upto(num_threads).map do
    ::Thread.new do
        loop do
            row = queue.pop
            puts "#{row[:user_id]}"
            count += 1
        end
    end
end

producer.join
threads.map(&:join)
puts "#{count}"
```

When I run the above code it appears to run all the threads and prints the values to the console, but then instead of printing the count it spits out the error:

```rb
delete_threads.rb:32:in `join': No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
    from delete_threads.rb:32:in `map'
    from delete_threads.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

Line 32 is `threads.map(&:join)`

I don't understand what this error means and how do I fix it? I'm especially curious as to why it seems like all the threads are processing just fine and then this error only gets thrown at the end of everything running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread#join` waits till a thread exits. Your threads are all infinite loops, so your main thread's `join` would wait forever, waiting for threads to finish, and the threads would wait forever looking at the queue that will not produce any more.

The easiest way to resolve this is for the producer to signal to the workers that no more elements would be forthcoming. For example, add this at the end of `Producer` (outside the loop):

```
queue << nil
```

Add this after `row = queue.pop`:

```
queue << nil and break unless row
```

The producer signals the end of data by queueing up a `nil`. The first consumer that finds `nil` will break out of its infinite loop, and exit the thread, allowing `.join` to happen, but not before it stuffs another `nil` into the queue, for the next thread to pop it. This is basically the foreman telling one worker the shift is over, then letting the news spread from neighbour to neighbour.

(This is not the only solution; there are many ways to resolve this, when you know what the problem is.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your answer. I will try this tomorrow!

Comment: Thank you again for the suggestion. Works perfectly! And the explanation helped me understand why it was failing in the first place.